# How to start on MS-Build

Tags: msbuild

I wish to start using MS-Build. I have lots of projects which I build manually (from Visual Studio) as of now. I want to automate build process and preferably from a machine onto which I don't wish to install Visual Studio. I started reading about MS-Build on MSDN. But I am yet to get a step by step guidance where to start and how to do. My questions are like:

1. How can I start MS-Build? Is there any download-able?
2. What is the first step?
3. How to create an MS-Build script?

And a lot similar questions. Can somebody guide me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MS Build comes with the .NET Framework itself and the executable (msbuild.exe) is located in the .NET-framework directory, something like (depending on version):

- C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
- C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
- C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

(The right version is also in %path% when using the "Visual Studio command prompt" from the start menu.)

MsBuild files are xml-files. You can start by making a new text file, lets say "c:\myscript.msbuild", and copy-paste this to the file:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="MyTarget" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="MyTarget">
    <Message Text="Hello world!" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Then go to command prompt and type:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe c:\myscript.msbuild

That is a good start. :)

Then you can customize the targets and properties.
Second example:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="All" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(MyCondition)' == 'x'" >
    <MyProperty>World2</MyProperty>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="MyTarget">
    <Message Text="Hello" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="$(MyProperty)" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="MyTarget2">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="All">
     <CallTarget Targets="MyTarget" />
     <CallTarget Targets="MyTarget2" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe c:\myscript.msbuild /target:mytarget /property:MyCondition=x

You can have also build files inside build-files.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="MyTarget" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="MyExternalProperties.msbuild"/>
  <Target Name="MyTarget">
    <Exec Command="echo Hello world 3"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is going to be the most decent start for me. I shall now learn how to write the build file for my project.

Answer (score 8):

MSBuild is similar to other build products like NAnt (just in case you've used one of those), but it is still different in a few respects.

[Here is a good start page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/0k6kkbsd%28v=vs.90%29) on MSDN. There are a truckload of different MSBuild task libraries released under various licences, most that i have seen are completely free to use and come with source code. Probably the two biggest are:

- the open source [MSBuild Community Tasks Project](https://web.archive.org/web/20200701145914/http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)
- the [SDC Tasks Library](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sdctasks) on codeplex

Other good places to get info:

- the [MSBuild team blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160221133806/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/msbuild/)
- [MSBuild Book](http://msbuildbook.com/)
- the blog of [Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi](http://sedodream.com/) (who is incredibly knowledgeable about the product but didn't work for MS until just recently). He also hangs out here on SO and may stumble across this question.

That should be enough to get started. If you can't find a task to do what you want, just write it yourseld - it is very easy.

Comment: Thanks. Though I could not make out much from the start page at MSDN, I hope, the other community projects will enhance my capabilities on MSBuild once I be able to use MSBuild.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the link to my book there as well. It is the best single source for info on MSBuild.