# Publish entire solution in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, publish, solution

I know how to publish a single application in my solution by right clicking the project name and clicking properties then going to publish tab. How do you do this for the entire solution so that you only have one installer for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have project references? If your project which you publish depends on another project, it should be automatically compiled also.

If you want to make more complex publishing scenarios, I recommend to use MSBuild or NAnt.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342314/how-to-start-on-ms-build/3342619) is a short tutorial of MSBuild.